# How to explicitly specify PARTITION in ActiveRecord SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, arel

I have a huge partitioned table and I know partition name in advance before executing SELECT query.

In vanilla SQL the syntax is `SELECT * FROM objects PARTITION (p1)`

My current workaround seems to be working but looks kind of hacky:

```ruby
active_record_relation.to_sql.gsub('FROM `objects`', "FROM `objects` PARTITION(#{explicit_partition_name})")
```

I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic ActiveRecord solution to this?

---

Just to be clear, I'm aware of [Partition Pruning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html) but I can't use it, because partition hashing/finding logic is an external component/system.

The database is MySQL if that's important.

Comment: There's a gem for that, but it hasn't been updated since 2016: https://github.com/mirakui/activerecord-mysql-index-hint I guess MySQL-specific features in the upstream ActiveRecord isn't in favor. TBH, all of ActiveRecord is pretty hacky. It's just a bunch of Ruby code that appends fragments of SQL together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just because I stumbled across this post you can construct that in a sideways manner

```
partition_name = 'p1'
active_record_relation.from(
  Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(
    active_record_relation.arel_table.name, 
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('PARTITION',[Arel.sql(partition_name)])
  )
)
```

This will produce the desired SQL

```
SELECT 
  objects.* 
FROM  
  objects PARTITION(p1)
```

Full Arel Example:

```
table = Arel::Table.new('objects')
table 
  .project(table[Arel.star])
  .from(Arel::Nodes::UnaryOperation.new(
          table.name, 
          Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('PARTITION',[Arel.sql('p1')])))
  .to_sql
```